# Azure Service Fabric creating a Scala stateless service

Tags: scala, azure

Just trying to build some ASF components in Scala on a Windows based infra. 
ASF API is in preview and is supposed to be working. 
Simply trying to import the required resources with SBT from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric?sort=newest

```
  lazy val asfSystem = "com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric" % "system-fabric-
  preview" % "1.0.0"
  lazy val asfTransport = "com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric" % "transport-
  preview" % "1.0.0"
  lazy val asfServices = "com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric" % "services-
  preview" % "1.0.0"

  lazy val asf = Seq(asfSystem, asfTransport, asfServices)

  libraryDependencies in ThisBuild ++= Dependencies.asf
```

Resources don't seem to exist

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric#transport-preview;1.0.0: public: unable to get resource for com/microsoft/azure/servicefabric#transport-preview;1.0.0: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/servicefabric/transport-preview/1.0.0/transport-preview-1.0.0.pom: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 502
[error] unresolved dependency: com.microsoft.azure.servicefabric#services-preview;1.0.0: public: unable to get resource for com/microsoft/azure/servicefabric#services-preview;1.0.0: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/servicefabric/services-preview/1.0.0/services-preview-1.0.0.pom: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 502
```

Is this a dead end?